# 30 page document takes one hour to compile

Tags: tikz-pgf, svg

I know that there are multiple questions of the kind "file takes too long to compile", but one whole hour for a 30-pages document seems abnormal to me. I'm using a custom LaTeX package, which is most likely to be the cause. The document includes hundreds of things like this:

```
\newcommand{\CARD}[2][]{%
    \raisebox{-2 pt}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \StrLeft{#2}{1}[\@@color]
            \StrRight{#2}{1}[\@@number]
            \cardsetup{#1, color=\@@color, number=\@@number}
            \draw[\bordercolor, line width = 0.9 pt] (-0.36, -0.24) rectangle (0.36, 0.24)
            (0,0) node {\nsymbol \! \csymbol}
            \cclue \nclue;
            \carddefault
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
}
```

where `\nsymbol \csymbol \cclue \nclue` are all instances of

```
\newcommand{\thing}{\scalerel*{%
        \def\svgwidth{10 pt}%
        \import{thing.pdf_tex}%
    }{X\rule[0ex]{0pt}{1pt}}%
}
```

Any idea about how to speed up things?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My guess is that with so little information, nobody here can give you useful advice. Please do some more research yourself, trying to narrow down the problem. When posting here, please provide a document showing the problem (or a link to a sample, if the document(s) are too many/too large).

Comment: Thanks! The actual file (and the custom .sty file) are available [here](https://github.com/SashaIr/hanabi-conventions). Does this help?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I cloned the repository and ran `pdflatex` on `hanabi.tex` three times (to get the references right). On my old Thinkpad (> 5 years, Linux, TeXlive 2020) each run took 42 seconds. It needed less than 200MB of main memory.

Comment: That is interesting (and a lot more reasonable time). Thanks a lot, at least now I know that the problem is not the code. The bad news is that I haven't the faintest idea about the possible cause.

Comment: Do you use Windows, Linux or MacOS? Is the directory with the document mounted as Windows share, Samba share or via some other network filesystem? If yes, try to compile it locally. Maybe there is a problem with IO. What's special about the document is that it opens 18000 files.

Comment: I'm on Windows, the folder is local but synced with OneDrive. I tried switching the syncing off and rerun `pdflatex`, but it still takes a lot of time.

Comment: Clone the repository to a new local folder and try again. If the problem persists, google for problems of Windows with opening 18000 files. If this is your document, then consider using `\newsavebox` or other techniques that avoid reading the files over and over again.

Comment: I didn't know about the `\newsavebox` command, but it's amazing, thanks a lot! The problem was indeed related to opening 18000 files, now that it only opens 16 it takes about one minute. I had to fix some spacing issues, but nothing major. Thank you again!